# Using aligned inside inferrule

Tags: math-mode, align

I am writing an deduction rule, and I want to break a long formula into multiple lines. I am using `inferrule` macro from `mathpartir` package to write the deduction rule. And my formula is like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}
$$
    \inferrule*{
        \psi(aaa)
    }{
        \psi(xxx\land yyy\land zzz)
    }
$$
\end{document}
```

But the real formula is longer, so I want to break it into multiple lines and I am using `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}
$$
    \inferrule*{
        \psi(aaa)
    }{
        \psi(\begin{aligned}xxx\\\land yyy\\\land zzz\end{aligned})
    }
$$
\end{document}
```

Then the compilation fails. I guess the problem is that `inferrule` redefined `\\` so `aligned` does work. How can I make it work?

Comment: Please post your `MWE` as in executable format..

Comment: @campa That's an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never heard of `mathpartir` before so I cannot say exactly what is going on here. The only thing I am sure of is that it has nothing to do with `amsmath` (which was actually my first guess), because also the snippet

```
% FAILS TOO
\newenvironment{foo}{}{}
\[
\inferrule*{
        \psi(aaa)
    }{
    \psi(\begin{foo}xxx\\\land yyy\\\land zzz\end{foo})
}
\]
```

fails. I guess it has to do with how `\inferrule` looks for and processes its arguments. Right now I haven't time to go through its code, but in many similar cases it helps to "protect" the inner environment by enclosing it in braces. In your case the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathpartir}
\begin{document}
\[
    \inferrule*{
        \psi(aaa)
    }{
        \psi({\begin{aligned}xxx\\\land yyy\\\land zzz\end{aligned}})
    }
\]
\end{document}
```

runs without problems. Please note that `$$` should be avoided in LaTeX, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917).

Comment: And it does work perfectly for my actual code. Thanks!

Comment: But for some reason, it appears that there has to be some character (if only a space) in between the `{` that opens the second argument of `\inferrule` and the `{` that opens the new group protecting the `aligned`.  `\inferrule*{aaa}{{\begin{aligned}xxx\\yyy\end{aligned}}}` yields an error, but `\inferrule*{aaa}{ {\begin{aligned}xxx\\yyy\end{aligned}}}` doesn't.

Comment: @MikeShulman Uhm, I've managed to track the error to a line of code which is followed by the comment "*last bug fix not extensively checked*", so I guess it has to do with that... `:-)`. As far as I see the trouble comes from a redefinition of ``\\``. If you use an `aligned`  without ``\\`` then it works with or without space after the opening brace. I'll try to look into it (but surely not before the weekend).